# Must declare the scalar variable "@MyNewID"

Tags: sql, sql-server, uniqueidentifier

I am trying to assign each row in the table 'Students' with a UniqueID by making use of a number pool (Hence the Table UNIQUE_NUMBERS).

I am unsure if my implementation is correct however I keep getting an error. Can someone please assist with the segment of code.

I am creating a a web application which adds/edits/deletes students in a database table. I am trying to ensure each user has a Unique identifier that doesn't exceed 8 Numerical values

```
CREATE TABLE DBO.UNIQUE_NUMBERS
(
  UNIQUE_NUMBER INT
)

INSERT INTO DBO.UNIQUE_NUMBERS (UNIQUE_NUMBER)
  VALUES ('1000')

DECLARE @MyNewID VARCHAR(8);
DECLARE @NextNo INT; 

UPDATE DBO.UNIQUE_NUMBERS
  SET UNIQUE_NUMBER = UNIQUE_NUMBER +1, @NextNo = UNIQUE_NUMBER;

SET @MyNewID = REPLACE(STR(@NextNo,8),'','0');

INSERT INTO DBO.STUDENTS (STUDENT_ID, STUDENT_FIRSTNAME, STUDENT_SURNAME)
  VALUES    ('SID'+ (SELECT * FROM DBO.UNIQUE_NUMBERS)  , 'Daenerys' , 'Targaryen' ),
        ('SID'+ @MyNewID , 'Jon' , 'Snow' ),
        ('SID'+ @MyNewID , 'Gregor' , 'Clegane' ),
        ('SID'+ @MyNewID , 'Arya' , 'Stark' ),
        ('SID'+ @MyNewID , 'Cersei' , 'Lannister' ),
        ('SID'+ @MyNewID , 'Joffrey' , 'Baratheon' ),
        ('SID'+ @MyNewID , 'Petyr' , 'Baelish' ),
        ('SID'+ @MyNewID , 'Khal' , 'Drogo' ),
        ('SID'+ @MyNewID , 'Theon' , 'Greyjoy' ),
        ('SID'+ @MyNewID , 'Ramsey' , 'Bolton' )
```

When I view the Data via the Web application view, The STUDENT_ID should display as the example below:

STD12345678

And then increment for the next student:

STD12345679

Comment: `@MyNewID` is a single variable, so your insert will insert the same value for all students since you are inserting multiple records at the same time.

Comment: `(SELECT * FROM DBO.UNIQUE_NUMBERS)` in a single record of your insert isn't going to work either as it will return multiple columns which cannot be implicitly concatenated with a string.

Comment: If you don't want to use a built in sequence you'll need to insert the rows 1 at a time and update your sequence table after each insert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about something like this -

```
create table #temp
    ( STUDENT_KEY INT identity (10000000,1),
    STUDENT_ID  AS CONCAT('STD',STUDENT_KEY),
    STUDENT_FIRSTNAME VARCHAR(255), 
    STUDENT_SURNAME VARCHAR(255)
    )

INSERT INTO #temp
VALUES  ( 'Daenerys' , 'Targaryen' ),
        ( 'Jon' , 'Snow' ),
        ( 'Gregor' , 'Clegane' ),
        ( 'Arya' , 'Stark' ),
        ( 'Cersei' , 'Lannister' ),
        ( 'Joffrey' , 'Baratheon' ),
        ( 'Petyr' , 'Baelish' ),
        ( 'Khal' , 'Drogo' ),
        ( 'Theon' , 'Greyjoy' ),
        ( 'Ramsey' , 'Bolton' )


SELECT * FROM #temp
```